# Best practise: nesting the given CSS in Sass

Tags: css, sass

What would be the 'best Sass' way to nest the following CSS?

```
.summary-features a,
.summary-description a,
.price .element_prijs1 {
  font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Leave it as it is** to avoid unnecessary complexity and/or redundancy. There is no such thing as 'best' nesting, but only 'correct' and 'incorrect' semantics.

In your example you could force a nesting like described by Neelam and Jeroen, but this will bring redundancy in and thus worse maintainability. Another option, just to demonstrate the thing with semantics, is to avoid redundancy and do it like this:

```
.summary-features,
.summary-description,
.price {
  a, .element_prijs1 {
    font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
  }
}
```

**which does not have the same semantics** as your CSS snippet. This way also `a` elements in `.price` will get bold and `.element_prijs1` in `.summary-features` and `.summary-description`. So again: just leave it as it is and don't use nesting as an end in itself. It's still valid Sass code.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert in all things sass, however this is one way of nesting your sass selectors:

```
.summary-features,
.summary-description {
   a {
      font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
   }
}

.price {
   .element_prijs1 {
     font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 'Problem' i have with maney of these solutions is that i find the orginal code 'better' because its less code?

Comment: @JordyVR If you prefer plain old CSS then by all means continue using it, I have provided a solution to your problem, other than the answers provided (which are valid may I add) there is no way to make the code "less" for you. These are the best solutions. If you want to use Sass the answers provided work and are best practise. I will add however that when the code is output after being precompiled it will look like CSS, the advantage with Sass is the fact that you can nest and see the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be the best:

```css
.summary-features, .summary-description {
    a {
        font-weight: $font-weight-bold;   
    }
}
.price {
    .element_prijs1 {
        font-weight: $font-weight-bold
    }
}
```